# Google Analytics Variant Testing different CSS files

Tags: php, jquery, google-analytics

In my ecommerce store I have a "checkout process" that consist of 3/4 pages. I want to run an experiment on this (A/B testing) with Google Analytics. Specifically; I want to try a different stylesheet that hides a couple of elements (`display:none;`) to make the checkout more simplistic.

Basically I want Google Analytics to use `global.css` for the "original" page and `global_b.css` for the "variant".

Making different variants for every page is not the ideal solution. In the documentation there is a soluton but I don't really understand how to implement this: https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/experiments-client-side#implement-choose.

How do I modify the given script to only work for the pages I want to test (e.g. `checkout_1.php`, `checkout_2.php`, `checkout_3.php`) and switch between the two stylesheets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I've approached this is to

1) Add an additional CSS class definition to global.css :

```
.ga-experiment-no-display{
    display:none;
}
```

2) Add an additional html class to each element that can be hidden on checkout_1|2|3.php, such as `'.ga-experiment'`

3) The Checkout pages each loads the GA experiment code and includes a JS file (checkout.js).  This has code that:

```
var chosenVariation = cxApi.chooseVariation();
if (chosenVariation > 0){
   //Search for all elements with $('.ga-experiment') 
   //Add the class '.ga-experiment-no-display'
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I (eventually) got it working using your advice. My only concern now is since I use this code on multiple pages; does the script generate a new `chosenVariation` for every page load? Or does it remember the users variation and keep displaying that?

Comment: GA will remember and return the same `chosenVariation` in most cases.  This won't apply if the user returns after 30 days (or your site GA cookie expiration), another browser, or clears cache/cookies. [See **Choose a variation for a user**](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/experiments#cxjs)